# Optimize where in delete in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-delete, large-data

I have a mysql performance problem : i have to update a large innodb table (approx. 1 million lines), deleting rows by thousands. Let's say it's items, coming from multiple sources. So, the table has a primary key item_id, an provider_id column identifying the provider of the item, and an external_id column (which is the id of this item in this provider, the way that this specific provider identify it) which has to be a varchar (several providers, several internal ways for them of identifying their items).

When i update, i go provider by provider, and i make a match/diff between a json file and the database, to know which items have to be added, updated or deleted. The match is on the external_id. When i have to delete items, i go with a query like `DELETE FROM table_items WHERE provider_id=A AND external_id IN (...)`.
Even if i make batches of 1k items, it's really slow.

Here's a simplified table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `annonce` (
    `annonce_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `annonce_id_externe` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `provenance_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `categorie_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`annonce_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_externe_par_provenance_et_categorie` (`annonce_id_externe`, `provenance_id`, `categorie_id`),
    INDEX `provenance_id` (`provenance_id`),
    INDEX `annonce_id_externe` (`annonce_id_externe`),
    INDEX `categorie_id` (`categorie_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `annonce_categorie_id` FOREIGN KEY (`categorie_id`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`categorie_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `annonce_provenance_id` FOREIGN KEY (`provenance_id`) REFERENCES `provenance` (`provenance_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

Any idea on making it faster ?

Thanks

Comment: With an Inner Join it may be faster.

Comment: You mean creating a dummy table with just the ids to delete inside, and join with it ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of data to know exactly how to work around it?

Comment: Prose can be harder to read, and less precise, than SQL.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And, I am unclear on whether you are having to parse _every_ row's JSON to do the statement.

Comment: I just added a simplified table definition in the main post.
For now, the main way i found out was to get primary key associated with external key, and to use it. I store the association between external_id and annonce_id in a json file, so i can quickly find out what items should be deleted from database.